# How to find the error rate when sklearn's roc_auc_score is used as metrics?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, metrics, roc

```
auc = roc_auc_score(CV_label, y_pred_proba) * float(100)
```

However, I am said that I cannot find the error using (100 - roc_auc_score).
I found a previously answered question about the equal error rate.
Link: [Equal Error Rate in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339746/equal-error-rate-in-python).
How do I find the error using only the roc_auc_score.

Comment: Can you clarify what error you want to calculate  exactly? I assume you are using "error rate" to mean 1 - accuracy, ie the proportion of misclassified examples? What does the EER have to do with it here?

Comment: I need to find the hyper param with the least error when ROC is used as metric. I have an imbalanced data with 60:20:20::train:CV:test as split. I am using KNN algorithm and I have to find the optimal 'K' value (the one with the least error) on CV data. How do I find it?

Comment: Calimo, I am using simple Cross Validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The ROC AUC is a summary of the ROC curve, and it is impossible to recover the information about a single point from the summarized metric.

You should use the `accuracy_score` metric instead:

```
accuracy = accuracy_score(CV_label, y_pred_proba)
```

Comment: I have an imbalanced dataset so I have chosen ROC as my metric.